# What should our logo and site design look like?

Tags: discussion, essential-meta-questions

*One of the tasks that we must complete in the beta is answering [the 7 essential meta questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/). I'm creating these meta questions here for us to work on.*

We should begin collecting ideas and suggestions for a site logo. Create and upload your suggestions as answers, and let the voting begin!

Make sure your logo suggestion works well in 16x16 because it must also be recognizable in the browser's favorite/bookmark icon (favicon). Bigger sizes don't have to be exactly identical but could include additional details. However, the logo should basically be the same at all sizes.

The highest voted answers would be the prime candidate. I guess the final decision could be made by the moderators or in an announced chat meeting, but I don't know.

Comment: As a toddler's parent, my immediate icon idea is a pacifier, but I'm not going to suggest that because it's too age-specific. Then again, any kind of toy is also rather age-specific. I also think that building an icon of several objects won't work because it will be cluttered and not self-explanatory, and won't be recognizable at 16x16 pixels. This is challenging!

Comment: I just looked into Google's image search for inspiration, searching for "growing up". There are many neat images among the noise! Other search words would be just as interesting I'm sure.

Answer (score 10):

Some common traffic signs could also be relevant, although I admit there are regional differences that might make a single choice hard.

[image: pedestrian walkway]

[image: caution: children]

Comment: I like how they are carrying briefcases, or are those iPads?

Comment: LOL! I think they're supposed to be school bags.

Answer (score 8):

Could we somehow make the logo look like nested outlined people (for lack of a better description, like a teenager standing behind a middle schooler behind a primary schooler behind a toddler behind a baby, then have our theme continue with the 'ages and stages' idea: a few baby things, then further down some toys, then something teenagery, then somebody in a cap and gown...?

Comment: Good concept idea! I like every bit except the *cap and gown*; that's too localized. I had to think for a while to realize you meant graduation. Gown sounded more like hospital to me...

Comment: @torbengb Thanks for the heads-up, I had no idea that wasn't fairly universal!

Comment: sounds like a good idea, but a stretch for 16x16 pixels.

Comment: @David I'm not a graphics person, but for the mini-icon could we do a big stick figure holding hands with a small one?

Comment: @hedge that sounds good. Someone should post a mockup. Color ideas?

Comment: @David Avoid the annoyingly stereotypical pink-and-blue or baby's room pastels and I'll be happy.

Answer (score 2):

I think one fairly universal small ritual is [measuring the children's height](http://www.google.at/search?hl=en&q=measuring%20a%20child%27s%20height). That would make for an empathic logo.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**For the logo**

I like the idea of hand-holding; a little hand in a big hand.  I have no idea if this can work as a 16*16 favicon.

I also like ideas above of 'nested dolls' or outlines parent and child.

**For the site 'look and feel'**

Things I think of when I think "parents; children; families" -

- baby blue and baby pink
- alphabet blocks
- Gold Stars for good effort
- crayons, finger painting, pasta art, etc
- feeding bottles & dummies / pacifiers
- teddy bears
- "onesies" / baby grows

Some of these would be good fits for aspects of the site design.  EG: For the *green accepted answer tick  check* a chunky crayon mark would be nice.  It's a little bit similar to the sketch / draft look of the present layout, but other elements will be very different, so I don't think it'd be too much of a problem.

Comment: I like the idea of using everyday items as graphical elements. We should also include items from everyday life with older kids.

Comment: While these ideas sound really nice and cute, I think it is too specific to the younger crowd.  Parenting wants to encourage more questions about adolescents and teens too and being overly focused on imagery from the younger years, is likely to do the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

There is an ad for this site running now which I think is fairly cute:

[image]

I'm not sure where this came from or who designed it, but it's cute.  Very warm.

Another one here:

[image]

Comment: Stack Exchange's own [Jin Yang](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/) made those great images.

Comment: Use 'em!!!!!!!!

Comment: Jin Yang did a great job - go with what we've got!!!  The colors are nice too, I couls see some of the greens from that background behind dad looking very nice as the color scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Building on HedgeMage's good idea, how about a stylized logo based on the Russian [babushka](http://www.google.at/search?q=babushka%20doll%20set) dolls-within-dolls?  (a.k.a. [matryoshka dolls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll))

The nesting feature of these could be like the outlines that HedgeMage suggested.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that the newborn's finger grabbing, as one of our very first interactions with our baby, could be a nice logo. I think that all of us remember the moment that our newly born child has grabbed that finger of ours and we realized who has just done what:)

[image: img2]
[image: img3]

Answer (score -1):

As for color choice and style, I think something like *Flintstones* would be good inspiration.
It's a kind of sketchy look, but not with pastels and baby colors, yet playful and imaginative.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

The tags could be nappy-safety pins?

Comment: We're already fighting the impression that this site is only for parents of babies and toddlers.  Baby-centric styling can only increase the problem.

Answer (score -2):

> ---

### Showing the life stages:

> ---

***New baby and new parents:***

[image]

***Dealing with a toddler:***

[image: enter link description here]

***The first lessons:***

[image]

***Teenagers aren't always a menace! ;)***

[image: enter link description here]

***The old age!***

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: These images resulted from Google search.

Comment: Well, it's the concept that counts.

Answer (score -2):

What about merging Torben Gundtofte-Bruun's and bobobobo's suggestions :

[image: large version]

[image: 16x16 version]

Answer (score -6):

Perhaps a 60's flower-power theme? I wasn't around at the time, but to me it means a laid-back, open-minded, and relaxed atmosphere, along with bright and cheerful colors. (We should probably avoid elements like LSD and pot, though!)

I'm just brainstorming here, so feel free to edit as you like, or to shoot it down with counterarguments :)

[image]
[image]