# Design of the Parenting site.

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should our logo and site design look like?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like)

Could we please have the parenting site have a better design, like the English Language stie where the design suits a site on language. Couldn't we please have a theme on children?